# how to make the dir function not printing the __init_subclass function?

Tags: python-3.x

I have that problem who says:create un empty class.

But when i run the code i got the following error:

```
 - [Got] ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'area']

(353 chars long) [stderr]:  (0 chars long) [Expected] ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'area']

(332 chars long) [stderr]: [Anything] (0 chars long)
```

And here is my code:

```
`#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Module implementing BaseGeometry class"""


class BaseGeometry:
    """Empty class"""
    pass
```

`

When I compare the result of my code and what they expected in the result I found that the problem is in the `__init_subclass.` It should not be in results of the `dir` function.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

> For example, all classes inherit from object, [...]

---

[See this section in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) as a reference. And as `object` has the `__init_subclass__` method, all inheriting classes have it too.

*Sidenote: These classes are called "New style classes", as previous in Python 2 you needed to explicitly inherit from* `object` *to have this behavior*